# Plotting big dataset of small numbers in exponational graf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot dataset of 26591*3 points with small values (4.3009317e-12 etc.) into a log axis. Sadly its taking insane amount of time to even show plot and when it does its all over the place. I am not really experienced with plotting in Python so every bit of help is highly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = [0.300024, 0.300048, 0.300072, 0.300096, 0.300120, 0.300144, 0.300168, 0.300191, 0.300215, 0.300239]
basic = [2.7704275e-11, 2.0084695e-11, 2.3364087e-11, 2.4630632e-11, 2.5054311e-11, 2.5193448e-11, 2.4049637e-11, 2.2442672e-11, 2.2988902e-11, 2.5071363e-11]
omega = [2.6312466e-09, 2.6502596e-09, 2.6910974e-09, 2.7384774e-09, 2.7859334e-09, 2.8240738e-09, 2.8580431e-09, 2.8980909e-09, 2.9313439e-09, 2.9388244e-09]
k = [1.4599796e-08, 1.4049786e-08, 1.377791e-08, 1.3684064e-08, 1.3645279e-08, 1.3552333e-08, 1.3475999e-08, 1.3534699e-08, 1.3692559e-08, 1.3646501e-08]


plt.plot(times, basic)
plt.plot(times, omega)
plt.plot(times, k)

plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlim(0, 2)

plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('log graph')

plt.show()
```

real data which are being used

Times

0.300024, 0.300048, 0.300072, 0.300096, 0.300120, 0.300144, 0.300168, 0.300191, 0.300215, 0.300239

Basic

2.7704275e-11, 2.0084695e-11, 2.3364087e-11, 2.4630632e-11, 2.5054311e-11, 2.5193448e-11, 2.4049637e-11, 2.2442672e-11, 2.2988902e-11, 2.5071363e-11

Omega

2.6312466e-09, 2.6502596e-09, 2.6910974e-09, 2.7384774e-09, 2.7859334e-09, 2.8240738e-09, 2.8580431e-09, 2.8980909e-09, 2.9313439e-09, 2.9388244e-09

K

1.4599796e-08, 1.4049786e-08, 1.377791e-08, 1.3684064e-08, 1.3645279e-08, 1.3552333e-08, 1.3475999e-08, 1.3534699e-08, 1.3692559e-08, 1.3646501e-08

Comment: So is your question how you can make it faster or how you can make it not "all over the place"? I don't think you can make it faster except for reducing the number of data points.

Comment: You didn't provide any test data nor an excerpt of your real data.  Matplotlib usually doesn't have problems plotting millions of points.  Are you sure your data is in numeric or date format (and not in string format)? You might want to add an image of the plot you did get. Can you explain what you mean by *"its all over the place"*?

Comment: In ideal case - both. 
I cant really reduce the number of data points, so making it faster might not be possible. 
About that "all over the place" i have a screenshot of plot but dont know if you can actually upload screenshots to stack overflow.. if not here is external link to it https://snipboard.io/13PsFe.jpg
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Updated the question with real data being used (10 of each)

Comment: As JohanC said - "Are you sure your data is in numeric or date format (and not in string format)" looks like data was actually in string instead of float - reformated and it looks much better! Thank you very much man!

Comment: in the code provided please define:  `times`, `basic`, `omega`, `k`....